# In Visual Studio 2022 what happens when I stop a debugging session for asp net core application running in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

When I press the Stop button in VS 2022 to stop a debugging session, what actually happens? I'm debugging an ASP.NET 5 web application with `hostingModel="InProcess"`, using IIS.

Does my application receive any notification that it's being stopped, e.g. will `ApplicationStopping` events run because the AppPool is stopping, or does the process just die immediately? Or does the worker process keep running and the debugger is just detached?